# Python - Creating github access token completely from terminal

Tags: python, github

I want the user to be able to enter a username and password which will then automatically generate an access token so that git actions afterwards will work... (evantually what I am trying to do is create an ssh key for the user all from the terminal)
Is this even possible? How can you do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm confused, why dont you just use the existing commands [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#configure-git) and maybe put them in a bash script ?

Comment: @LouisAT because in order for the ssh key to work you need to manually sign in to their website and copy it into there, I want that to happen automatically

Comment: @LouisAT: OP mentions a GitHub access token; GitLab can't create GitHub access tokens as those are specific to GitHub. It's not clear to me whether you can do this at all: the [gh cli](https://docs.github.com/en/github-cli/github-cli/about-github-cli) does not seem to have a request to do it. However, for the "eventually" part (creating an ssh key), `gh` *does* have support.

Comment: Limiting yourself specifically to Python seems pointless. Consider using the [tag:github-cli] `gh`.